# Clarification on solr configuration level

Tags: tomcat, solr4

A very good day.

I deployed solr.war under tomcat deployment directory. The default instance directory is as 'collection1'.
I could not find where the path is specified and nothing is mentioned in solrConfig.xml

How can I locate/change the default instance directory name?

Please anyone can advice...

Comment: Hi,

There is no such file called 'solr.xml' in deployment directory.
There is file called 'solrConfig.xml'

Though I did test the following cases 
1) I placed solr.xml file under solr folder and did changes as you said
2) I placed solr.xml file classes folder and did changes as you said
3) I did add the below content in solrConfig.xml

no results

Answer (score 0):

In solr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>


<solr persistent="true">

    <core name="collection1" instanceDir="collection1" />

  </cores>
</solr>
```

Here you core name is collection1 and directory pointing to collection1 folder
you can change the core name and point to your own directory.

Comment: Hi,There is no such file called 'sorl.xml' in deployment direcotry.
There is file called 'solrConfig.xml'

Though I did test the fowllowing cases 
1) I placed solr.xml file under solr folder and did changes as you said
2) I placed solr.xml file classes folder and did changes as you said
3) I did add the below content in sorlCofig.xml


no results

Answer (score 0):

I don't have privilege to comment

follow the intruction
1)
Check

```
     <env-entry>

       <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
       <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
       <env-entry-value>D:\solr\conf\</env-entry-value>       

    </env-entry>
```

in web.xml file

2)copy the solr.xml in the directory mentioned in env-entry-value

3)core name i.e collection1 folder should be present in same directory.
inside that conf folder should be present and inside that solrConfig.xml and other solr related files will be present

ex: collection1/conf/solrConfig.xml(other files as well)

test your application

Hope it's clear now.